# Extra Characters at the end of Vigenere cs50 Pset2

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I am new to coding and have been doing it for a couple of weeks. I am now taking the cs50 course and Ive written the code for pset2 vigenere. When I used check50, I realized it wanted me to account for spaces and non-letters without skipping ahead in the key.

I added the "j--;" and, although the code is correct, it now creates extra random characters at the end of the ciphertext.

Also, when checking argv[1] for just letters in my code I have an if statement that has "int key = argv[1][i];" in the body. It doesn't do anything but I don't know how to have it just continue checking the next char without having an empty body, which is not allowed.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[0])

{
    //making sure it is not more than one command line
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere key \n");
        return 1;
    }

    //if it is one command line, making sure the input is just letters      
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(argv[1][i]))
            {    
                int key = argv[1][i];
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Usage: ./vigenere key \n");
                return 1;
            }
        }   

    }
    //asking user for input text
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext:");

    //going through a loop to turn plain text into ciphertext 
    int i = 0; 
    int n = strlen(plaintext); 
    string key = argv[1];


    //looping through the key    
    while (i < n)

    {

        for (int j = 0, m= strlen(key); j < m; j++, i++)

        {   
            //using the asci of each char as an int
            int asc = (plaintext[i]);
            int k = key[j];
            //if lowercase
            if (k >= 97 && k <= 122)
            {
                k -= 97;
            }
            else
            {
                k -= 65;
            }

            //if lowercase
            if (asc >= 97 && asc <= 122)
            {
                printf("%c", ((((asc - 97) + k) % 26) + 97));
            }
            //if uppercase
            else
            {
                if (asc >= 65 && asc <= 90)
                {
                    printf("%c", ((((asc - 65) + k) % 26) + 65));
                }
                //if non-letter
                else
                {  
                    printf("%c", asc);
                    j--;

                }
            }

        }  


    }


    printf("\n");

}
```

These are the expected vs actual results:

```
key: baz
plaintext: hello, world!
expected ciphertext: iekmo, vprke!

actual ciphertext:   iekmo, vprke!!pu
```

Comment: Have you looked at the other questions with the tags [tag:cs50] and [tag:vigenere] to see how those programs (probably those in the answers more than those in the questions) do it?  If you type `[c] [cs50] [vigenere]` in the search area, you get 71 questions, including this one.  Somewhere in amongst those is the insight you need.

Comment: The most common reason for 'extra characters' is that you did not null terminate your string properly — have you checked that you do null terminate the string.

Comment: You have `int main(int argc, string argv[0])` — the `0` is unorthodox and best omitted.  It's best to report errors on `stderr` (use `fprintf(stderr, …)` in place of `printf(…)`).  You report a usage error when there is no key, and also when there is a non-alphabetic character in the key.  It would be better to use a different error message when a key is provided but contains non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Usage: ./vigenere key \n");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`. 2) the same executable does not care what the name of the executable is so should use the actual name, as pointed to by: `argv[0]`  A useful example would be: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <key>\n", argv[0] );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because program increments `i` here `for (int j = 0, m= strlen(key); j < m; j++, i++)`, it allows reading past the end of plaintext. The while loop is not going to evaluate `i` until after the for loop is done. And this has potential for an infinite loop, depending on what the contents of memory are after the end of plaintext. If it never encounters something in the a-z or A-Z range, it will `j--` forever.

You need to break out of the for loop if and when `i == strlen(plaintext)`.